# Laravel $auth calling function as $auth->functionname rather than $auth->function()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I came across some code in Laravel where a function was defined in a user model which extends the Authenticable class. The function is called in a view via `$auth`, like so:
`$auth->function_name`
Why is it called this way rather than like so:
`$auth->function_name()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating over a related model the functions is accessed as a property.
 I found a solution in the laravel documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#relationship-methods-vs-dynamic-properties